# Introspect the id_token to send claims from token to microservices? Ocelot and OpenIdDict

Tags: .net, .net-core, openiddict, ocelot

I am using ocelot api gateway to authenticate the request and pass the claims to the underlying micro services. So far i am able to get the access_token as well as the id_token. Is there a way i can introspect the id_token so that the claims from both of the token can be sent to the microservices?
Here is my code:

```
using Ocelot.DependencyInjection;
using Ocelot.Middleware;
using OpenIddict.Validation;
using OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("ocelot.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(o =>
{
    o.DefaultScheme = OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
});
builder.Services.AddOpenIddict()
    .AddValidation(options =>
    {
        // Note: the validation handler uses OpenID Connect discovery
        // to retrieve the address of the introspection endpoint.
        options.SetIssuer("https://localhost:7013/");
        options.AddAudiences("ApiGateway");
        options.SetClientId("ApiGateway");
        options.SetClientSecret("apigateway-secret");
        options.UseIntrospection();
        options.UseSystemNetHttp();
        options.UseAspNetCore();
    });
var configuration = new OcelotPipelineConfiguration
{
    PreAuthorizationMiddleware = async (ctx, next) =>
    {
        await next.Invoke();
    }
};
builder.Services.AddOcelot(builder.Configuration);
var app = builder.Build();
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseOcelot(configuration).Wait();
app.Run();
```